# Yet another polymorphism problem in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, class, polymorphism

I have a base class:

```
import { mapKeys } from 'lodash'

export function initModel<T>(this: T, data: Partial<T>): void {
  for (const key in data) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(data, key)) {
      this[key] = data[key]
    }
  }
}

export class BaseModel {
  static mapFields: Record<string, string> = {}

  constructor(data?: Partial<BaseModel>) {
    initModel.call(this, data)
  }

  static parse<RawT, T extends BaseModel>(rawData: RawT): T {
    return Object.prototype.constructor.call(
      this,
      mapKeys(rawData, (_, k) => this.mapFields[k]),
    )
  }
}
```

and a specific one:

```
export class Employee extends BaseModel {
  id: number
  image: string
  position: string
  department: string
  name: string
  lastEvent: Date

  static mapFields = {
    id: 'id',
    image: 'image',
    position: 'position',
    department: 'department',
    name: 'name',
    last_event: 'lastEvent',
  }

  static parse(rawData: RawEmployee): Employee {
    const result = super.parse<RawEmployee, Employee>(rawData)
    result.lastEvent = new Date(result.lastEvent)
    return result
  }
}
```

RawEmployee class which used by Employee parse method:

```
export class RawEmployee {
  id: number
  image: string
  position: string
  department: string
  name: string
  last_event: string
}
```

TypeScript shows me an error with such overriding of parse method:

TS2417: Class static side 'typeof Employee' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof BaseModel'.   Types of property 'parse' are incompatible.     Type '(rawData: RawEmployee) => Employee' is not assignable to type '<RawT, T extends BaseModel>(rawData: RawT) => T'.       Types of parameters 'rawData' and 'rawData' are incompatible.         Type 'RawT' is not assignable to type 'RawEmployee'.

How to correctly implement it?

Comment: What is `RawEmployee`?

Comment: @gurisko I added it.

Comment: have you found the workaround? it looks.like a bug in TS...

Comment: @Jerome yes I can create a middleware class as a copy of BaseModel but without parse method, then extend Employee from it and switch super call to BaseModel call. As a workaround it can work well. I'm still in research.

Comment: playing with your code, I found that if I change the name of your `parse` static method by `parsing`  or anything else, the eslint warning disappeard... Don't know if there is somewhere a conflict in this static naming

Comment: @Jerome That is because you aren't overriding the method anymore but adding a new one, so that tslint has no reason to warn.

Comment: in that case why just not calling the parse method in this static instead of overriding it?

Comment: @Jerome To keep Model interface.

Answer (score 0):

the following code is not working ?

**[EDIT]**
This code is no longer raising any error.

```
"typescript": "^4.0.2"
"lodash": "^4.17.20",
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.161",
```

However, please note the following:

1- in your `initModel` function there is something wrong that could be bypassed by adding null assertion (please note the `!`) when setting the `this[key]`. I understood that if part of the keys of the class extending BaseModel are in passed in the constructor, you are setting them. Seems Typescript doesn't like the `partial` here. Since I do not understand the test if Object.prototype.***, I am not sure to undertand the real goal of this `initModel` function. There might be another way to write it to avoid the awful `!`

2- According to the types definition of the lodash mapKeys function, you need to pass an object as argument. As a result, your `rawT` type should extend `Record<string, any>` (or Record<whateveryouwant, whateveryouwant>

```
import { mapKeys } from "lodash";

export function initModel<T>(
    this: T,
    data: Partial<T>
): void {
    for (const key in data) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(data, key)) {
            this[key] = data[key]!;
        }
    }
}

export class BaseModel {
    static mapFields: Record<string, string> = {};

    constructor(data?: Partial<BaseModel>) {
        data && initModel.call(this, data);
    }

    static parsing<RawT extends Record<string, any>, T extends BaseModel>(
        rawData: RawT
    ): T {
        return Object.prototype.constructor.call(
            this,
            mapKeys(rawData, (_: any, k: any) => this.mapFields[k])
        );
    }
}

export class Employee extends BaseModel {
    id: number;
    image: string;
    position: string;
    department: string;
    name: string;
    lastEvent: Date;

    static mapFields = {
        id: "id",
        image: "image",
        position: "position",
        department: "department",
        name: "name",
        last_event: "lastEvent",
    };

    static parse(rawData: RawEmployee): Employee {
        const result = super.parsing<RawEmployee, Employee>(rawData);
        result.lastEvent = new Date(result.lastEvent);
        return result;
    }
}

export class RawEmployee {
    id: number;
    image: string;
    position: string;
    department: string;
    name: string;
    last_event: string;
}
```

Comment: I added mapKeys and initModel functions in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I ended up with this solution:

```
export class BaseModel {
  static mapFields: Record<string, string> = {}

  constructor(data?: Partial<BaseModel>) {
    initModel.call(this, data)
  }

  static parse(rawData: Record<string, unknown>): BaseModel {
    return Object.prototype.constructor.call(
      this,
      mapKeys(rawData, (_, k) => this.mapFields[k]),
    )
  }
}

export class RawEmployee implements Record<string, unknown> {
  [x: string]: unknown
  id: number
  image: string
  position: string
  department: string
  name: string
  last_event: string
}

export class Employee extends BaseModel {
  id: number
  image: string
  position: string
  department: string
  name: string
  lastEvent: Date

  static mapFields = {
    id: 'id',
    image: 'image',
    position: 'position',
    department: 'department',
    name: 'name',
    last_event: 'lastEvent',
  }

  static parse(rawData: RawEmployee): Employee {
    const result = super.parse(rawData) as Employee
    result.lastEvent = new Date(result.lastEvent)
    return result
  }
}
```

It is no so perfect since I need to override parse method in all models even though it has no difference with original. And type guard `as` is required for super call.